# How to pass DNS validation for internal cluster domain for a kubernetes cert-manager ACME certificate

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I run a kubernetes cluster with cert-manager installed for managing ACME (Let's Encrypt) certificates. I'm using DNS domain validation with Route 53 and it works all fine.

The problem comes when I try to issue a certificate for a cluster internal domain. In this case domain validation does not pass since the validation challenge is presented on external Route53 zone only, while cert-manager is trying to look for domain name via cluster internal DNS.

Any hints on how this can be solved are welcome.

Comment: Where is the authoritative DNS for the internal domain?

Comment: I guess it is inside kubernetes cluster because I'm using default kubernetes settings. Curious if it is possible to configure kubernetes DNS to "show" also the external Route53 records for internal domain, to applications running inside the cluster.

Comment: `...cluster internal domain` - you meant `cluster.local`?

Comment: Yes, however we configured it to something like cluster.domain.com where cluster.domain.com is also managed also by Route53 (for external consumers).

Comment: Could you attach yamls (that would be helpful to reproduce your issue)? Also, which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: This is a bare metal installation. Kubernetes 1.18.10.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't control public DNS for your cluster internal domain, you will not be able to receive LetsEncrypt certificates for it.

You may however set up another issuer that will grant you certificates for this domain, e.g. the SelfSigned issuer: https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/selfsigned/
Then set the `issuerRef` of your certificate object to point to your SelfSigned issuer:

```yaml
(...)
  issuerRef:
    name: selfsigned-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    group: cert-manager.io
```